# Subsetting observations based on a duplicate values

Tags: r

How do I retain just one observation in my dataset when the dataset contains two columns with duplicate values? For example if this is my dataset below:

```
row1 & row 2 
col(Sepal.Length) and col(Petal.Length)
```

contain similar values `(5.1, 1.4)`, `(5.1, 1.4)`

I want to remove the second row and just retain the first row.

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          5.1         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          5.0         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Reproducible test data:

```
test12 <- head(iris)
test12[2,1] <- 5.1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `duplicated` to compare those specific columns:

```
test12[!duplicated(test12[,c(1,3)]),]
## or referencing the column names themselves:
test12[!duplicated(test12[,c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length")]),]

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6          5.0         0.2  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep only the first row:

```
    row1 <- test12[1, ]
```

To drop the second row of your dataFrame:

```
    dropRow <- test12[-2, ]
```